# Search for text contained in any row of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `DataFrame`

```
pred[['right_context', 'PERC']]
Out[247]: 
                          right_context      PERC
0  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  0.000197
1                San Pedro xxxxxxxxxxxx  0.572630
2          zxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  0.572630
3             de San Pedro Este parcela  0.572630
4   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  0.035577
```

And I have another pandas `DataFrame` called `_direcciones` with real addresses:

```
388427          SAN PEDRO              1
388428     bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb      1
388429        yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy      1
[388430 rows x 2 columns]
```

I need to somehow search if some address in `_direcciones` **is contained** in the first `DataFrame`, What I have done is:

```
[True for y in pred.right_context 
   for x in _direcciones.entity_content 
   if re.match(r'^%s\b' %x, y, flags=re.I)]
```

But it is very slow, and, more importantly, I would like to append to the first `DataFrame` a column with values `True|False` if an address was found, but currently I can't because the above code can return any number of rows, not exactly `5`, like I would need for the first `DataFrame`.

Something like this:

```
pred[['right_context', 'PERC']]
Out[247]: 
                          right_context      PERC    found?
0  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  0.000197       F
1                San Pedro xxxxxxxxxxxx  0.572630       T
2          zxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  0.572630       F
3             de San Pedro Este parcela  0.572630       T
4   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  0.035577       F
```

## Update

Thanks for the answers, but I am facing the same issue, `_direcciones` is so large that the chances that in `pred.right_context` exists a word in `_direcciones` are very high. For example:

### pred

```
0    URBANA. OBRA NUEVA TERMINADA. Urbana
1                  San Pedro número xxxxx
```

Here, I am looking for `San Pedro`, but both `San Pedro` and `URBANA` are in `_direcciones`, so both rows will be `True`. I do not know how to approach the problem.

Comment: @Erfan I think it is not the same thing, I've already tried using `isin` without success. Will give it another thought however.

Comment: Fair enough, will remove my close vote

Comment: @Erfan Thanks, to confirm it, this for example does not work `sum(_direcciones.entity_content.isin(['SAN PEDRO xxxxxx']))` it is equal to 0 when it should be 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) & [`str.upper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.upper.html)

You cann use `Series.str.contains` and join the column in `_direcciones` as one string with `|` as seperator.

Also important to note that we have to cast the string of dataframe `pred` to uppercase with `str.upper`

```
pred['found?'] = pred['right_context'].str.upper()\
                                      .str.contains('|'.join(_direcciones['Address']))
```

---

```
print(pred)
                          right_context      PERC  found?
0  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  0.000197   False
1                San Pedro xxxxxxxxxxxx  0.572630    True
2          zxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  0.572630   False
3             de San Pedro Este parcela  0.572630    True
4   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  0.035577   False
```

## Only get `T` & `F`

```
pred['found?'] = pred['right_context'].str.upper()\
                                      .str.contains('|'.join(_direcciones['Address']))\
                                      .astype(str).str[:1]
```

---

```
print(pred)
                          right_context      PERC found?
0  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  0.000197      F
1                San Pedro xxxxxxxxxxxx  0.572630      T
2          zxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  0.572630      F
3             de San Pedro Este parcela  0.572630      T
4   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  0.035577      F
```

## Output of `'|'.join`

```
'|'.join(_direcciones['Address'])

'SAN PEDRO|bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'
```

Comment: I am facing the problem with both answers, `_direcciones` is so large that I am getting `found?` all to true

Comment: Then how do you want to prevent that? Apparently the address is present for all dirreciones? Is there a way to group your data in separate groups? @ElBaulP

Comment: no, but it is highly likely that some word in `pred` is in `_direcciones`.

Comment: Then its logical that you get lot of/all `True` right? @ElBaulP

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to identify the correct one, and it seems with this approach it does not work. However, I am going to accept one of the answers. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Use word boundaries with all strings joined by `|` with [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and parameter `case=False`:

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in _direcciones['entity_content'])
pred['found?'] = pred['right_context'].str.contains(pat, case=False)
print (pred)
                          right_context      PERC  found?
0  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  0.000197   False
1                San Pedro xxxxxxxxxxxx  0.572630    True
2          zxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  0.572630   False
3             de San Pedro Este parcela  0.572630    True
4   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  0.035577   False
```

If necessary add [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in _direcciones['entity_content'])
pred['found?'] = np.where(pred['right_context'].str.contains(pat, case=False), 'T', 'F')
print (pred)
                          right_context      PERC found?
0  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  0.000197      F
1                San Pedro xxxxxxxxxxxx  0.572630      T
2          zxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  0.572630      F
3             de San Pedro Este parcela  0.572630      T
4   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  0.035577      F
```

Comment: I am facing the problem with both answers, `_direcciones` is so large that I am getting `found?` all to true

Comment: @ElBaulP - Is possible some value in `_direcciones['entity_content']` is empty string?

Comment: Yes!, I removed right now, I am going to try again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach, seems to work for me using small data sample:

```
from pprint import pprint
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def main():
    #Sample Data
    df_right = pd.DataFrame({'right_context':'San Jose, San Pedro, San Pedro Este, Santani, Honolulu'.split(','),
                       'PERC': np.arange(5)})
    directions = pd.DataFrame({'address':'SAN PEDRO, Djiloboji, Torres'.split(','),
                       'value': np.arange(3)})
    # generate found result
    found=(df_right['right_context'].str.contains('San Pedro', case=False)).tolist()
    # Insert into original dataframe
    df_right.insert(2,"found",found)
    pprint(df_right)

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
     right_context  PERC  found
0         San Jose     0  False
1        San Pedro     1   True
2   San Pedro Este     2   True
3          Santani     3  False
4         Honolulu     4  False
```

Comment: @ElBaulP, have you tried this snippet?
It seems to work for your latest edit as well.