# Create a column based on column value and a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df where I would like to create a new column with values based on the match between a list and another column.

This is the mock df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{'fruit': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Clementine', 'Dragon fruit', 'Elderberry', 'Figs', 'Grapes'],
'bites': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

With this list:

```
good = ['Apple', 'Clementine', 'Figs', 'Grapes']
```

I tried to create the desired column with:

```
df['good']= np.where(df['fruit']== good, 'good', 'not good')
```

This is what I would like to achieve. Notice that I prefer this text instead of a boolean.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for check membership:

```
df['good']= np.where(df['fruit'].isin(good), 'good', 'not good')
print (df)
          fruit  bites      good
0         Apple      1      good
1        Banana      2  not good
2    Clementine      3      good
3  Dragon fruit      1  not good
4    Elderberry      2  not good
5          Figs      3      good
6        Grapes      4      good
```

Comment: I knew that it would be something easy. Thanks.

Comment: can I use "isin" and a list when modifying string columns as well? i.e. something like str.split.inlist or similar?

Comment: @Mactilda - Do you think sometthing like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56021667/2901002) ? Only change column by list like `pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in good)`